# Drawing a responsive diagonal line

Tags: canvas, split, line, diagonal

This is what I want: a page split in two vertical parts: a red one with contents (200px in the fiddle) + the right part is a diagonal that goes top-left (200, 0) to bottom-right of the browser window.

I'd like this line to be responsive to any page changing: every time the page is resized, this line'd be always a neat diagonal between these points. (200, 0 - very bottom-right of the browser window)

I've been trying to manage the canvas function, but may be the wrong way.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick, check comments for info:

```js
// Get the canvas and the context to draw in
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function diagonalLineToBottomRight(){
  // Reset your canvas to the size of the window - this also clears the canvas
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  // Set a line color
  context.strokeStyle = 'red';
  // Set the point where you line starts
  context.moveTo(200, 0);
  // Draw the line to the bottom corner
  context.lineTo(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  // Actually draw the pixels to the canvas
  context.stroke();
}

// Set the function to execute when the window size changes
window.addEventListener('resize', diagonalLineToBottomRight, false);
// Execute the function on initial load
diagonalLineToBottomRight();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

I am guessing, however, you don't want your canvas to overlap the content on the side. This can be done by combining some CSS and JS to make a canvas that is 200 pixels *less wide* than you page:

```js
// Get the canvas and the context to draw in
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function diagonalLineToBottomRight(){
  // Reset your canvas to the size of the window - this also clears the canvas
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 200;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  // dont draw when its not wide enough
  if(window.innerWidth - 200 < 200) return;
  // Set a line color
  context.strokeStyle = 'red';
  // Set the point where you line starts
  context.moveTo(0, 0);
  // Draw the line to the bottom corner
  context.lineTo(window.innerWidth - 200, window.innerHeight);
  // Actually draw the pixels to the canvas
  context.stroke();
}

// Set the function to execute when the window size changes
window.addEventListener('resize', diagonalLineToBottomRight, false);
// Execute the function on initial load
diagonalLineToBottomRight();
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}
canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<nav></nav>
```

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. 
Now I just need to turn it off for widths less than the <nav> width.
Thank you!

Comment: if that's what you were looking for then please mark it as answer.